# How to connect to a proxy using PHP? How to make PHP search for strings on website?

Tags: php, curl, proxy, connection, bots

I am currently in a project and i need to put my php app connecting to a proxy.
I tried Curl in many ways, but i couldnt find out what am i doing wrong, i always get errors and more errors. All the code i found has no explanation and no commented code.
How can i connect to a proxy using PHP and make PHP search for strings on a website?

I tried this(with other proxy confs):

```html
$ch = curl_init(); 
    $timeout = 5; // set to zero for no timeout 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://proxy.example.com"); //your proxy url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, "8080"); // your proxy port number 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "username:pass"); //username:pass 
    $file_contents = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch); 
    return $file_contents;
```